# DataGridView Drag'n'Drop extended functionality

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have some DataGridView functionality which replaces data from dragged to dropped row (few columns of data).
But this is only inside visible range of DGV.

What if I should drop taken data in row which is 100 rows after visible area or 50 rows before?
Actually, I know how to drop since I subclass my DGV's:

```
Protected Overrides Sub onDragDrop(ByVal e As DragEventArgs)

    Dim p As Point = Me.PointToClient(New Point(e.X, e.Y))
    dropindex = Me.HitTest(p.X, p.Y).RowIndex
    If (e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move AndAlso Not cancelDrop) Then
        Dim dragRow As DataGridViewRow = CType(e.Data.GetData(GetType(DataGridViewRow)), DataGridViewRow)
        RaiseEvent Dropped(dragindex + 1, dropindex + 1)
    End If
    cancelDrop = False
    MyBase.OnDragDrop(e)
End Sub
```

But here seems essential how to scroll DGV with pressed left mouse button to be able to drop on some far row since MouseWheel and keyboard don't work with button down...

How do people solves such situations?

EDIT/SOLUTION:
With some tips and suggestions from varocarbas I find this code and slightly adapt it to ma needs and for now I can say this work OK. Maybe a little bit of "esthetic coding" will be needed for those which like nice code and more better functionality.

But for me this is OK.
Keep all your drag/drop code unchanged und just add this to DragOver handler.
(In my case it is in subclass since I want that all my datagrid's have those functions).

```
Protected Overrides Sub onDragOver(ByVal e As DragEventArgs)

    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move

    Try
        If e.Y <= PointToScreen(New Point(Me.Location.X, Me.Location.Y)).Y + 40 Then
            Me.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex -= 1
        End If
        If e.Y >= PointToScreen(New Point(Me.Location.X + Me.Width, Me.Location.Y + Me.Height)).Y - 10 Then
            Me.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex += 1
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.Print(ex.Message)
    End Try

    MyBase.OnDragOver(e)
End Sub
```

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_controls/datagrid/article.php/c14903/Tip-Auto-Scroll-While-Implementing-Drag--Drop-for-Reordering-Rows-in-DataGridView.htm

Well, I would rather like that somebody post improved solution instead that I reply to my own post.
I test this on DGV with 75 rows and .FullRowSelect=True and AllowDrop=True. If you press left mouse button and drag it to upper or lower bound (by height - Y) of visible grid it will scroll until you release a button or return mouse pointer inside a grid.
I also put a code in Try/Catch block to avoid checking of grid's data bounds.

Comment: What you want does not follow the standard behaviour and thus you have to do a custom implementation. Rough ideas: track when the mouse is close to the X/Y boundary (get position of the mouse and compare it with the position of the visible, boundary cells in each moment); if the mouse is within the area close to the boundary (a bit "before it") you have to check whether it moves in the "right direction" (e.g., if it close to the right boundary, it has to be moving rightwards); affect the scrolling on account of all this (e.g., via FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex/row...)

Comment: ... together with these basic ideas, you have to bear in mind that when dragging, quite a few events do not work (what will do the tracking not so easy); on top of all this, DataGridView is not the most user-friendly control from the events point of view precisely... In summary: this is not a straightforward implementation (and thus is not too likely that someone will write a valid code for you), but shouldn't be too difficult either if you work on it with clear ideas. Also if you write some code and come here back with specific doubts, you would most likely get help.

Comment: Hello varocarbas. First of all I have to get informations on how things stand with this, then to see maybe some part of code exists somewhere since I suppose I am not first interested for something like this and at least if needed it would not be too hard to write code for that if no other way exists.

Comment: No, you are not the first one who asks this; but as you can see (https://www.google.com/search?q=scroll+while+drag+and+drop+vb.net&oq=scroll+while+drag+and+drop+vb.net&aqs=chrome..69i57.12020j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#es_sm=93&espv=210&q=scroll+when+drag+and+drop+vb.net), most of the questions are for "easier controls" and, in any case, solutions always involve something on the lines of what I suggested (= a custom development is required for each control). Feel free to wait here for as long as you wish, perhaps you get lucky :)

Comment: ... the reason why I wrote these comments is cheering you a bit up because of the lack of response. Your question is perfectly fine and getting an adequate answer would certainly be a positive thing (for you and for future readers). I will not do that (writing a proper answer) but felt that I had to contribute in some way...

Comment: OK varocarbas, if you find interesting then involve yourself in thema as you wish. If no responses will be I will post my final solution (when finish a code) for help others...

Comment: Excellent attitude! As said, I will be more than happy to help on any specific issue you need some help on; but creating from scratch something I haven't done before (not too complex but neither too simple) sounds too much as an answer here. I look forward to see your code.

Comment: Here it is usable solution :)

Comment: Happy to read that! If it works (cannot test it now), you should write it as an answer and mark the answer as the right one; also if you could write down a brief summary of the conditions under which it works (what you tested), it would be excellent.